# Prove that if $A$ has a maximum, then the maximum must be the supremum

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

> *Prove that given $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, if has a maximum $a_0$, then $a_0$ must be the supremum.*

In order to prove this, I have written the following:

Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, nonempty set because $a_{0}$ $\in A$ for hypotesis. Then, since $a_{0}$ $\in A$ is the largest element of the set $A$   (i.e. for each element $A$ of A we have that $ a\leq a_{0}$) $A$ is bounded above. Then, A has a supremum. Let $s$ be the least upper bound of $A,$ so we have that for each element $a$ of $A$, $a\leq s$, for being $s$ an upper bound. In particular, $a_0\leq s$, which implies that $s=a_0$.

Then, we have that $\sup(A)=\max(A)=a_0$, which is exactly what we wanted to prove.

Observation: this proof is true if $s \in A$

I'm not sure if my proof is correct. I will be thankful if someone tells me.

Comment: Yes that's correct. Notice that $a_0$ is an upper bound of $A$ with $a_0\leq s$. This implies that $s=a_0$ as you mentioned, since $s$ was the least upper bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not be given the fact that $A$ is bounded from above.  It is not empty because it contains $a_0$.  Since $a_0$ is its maximum, then $A$ is bounded from above by $a_0+1$.  Hence it is not empty and it is bounded from above. 
 Since it is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, it has a supremum.

Let $b$ be the supremum of $A$.  Since $a_0\in A$, $a_0 \le b$.  Now you need to show that $a_0 \ge b$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given.  Since $b$ is the supremum of $A$, there is an $x \in A$ such that $b - \epsilon \le x$.  But then
$$
b - \epsilon \le x \le a_0
$$
since $a_0$ is the maximum of $A$.  Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, we can conclude that
$$
b \le a_0
$$ 
Hence $a_0=b$.

Comment: $A$ is not necessarily open e.g. $A=[0,1]+\{2\}$, $b-\epsilon$ need not to be in $A$. The condition is that there exists an $a\in A$ such that $a\ge b-\epsilon$.

Comment: You're right.  Thanks.  I'll fix it.

Comment: @zwim, thanks so much for the constructive help.  I love that about Mathstackexchange.  In fact the singleton set $\{2\}$ makes your point quite well.

Comment: I have one little question @EricFisher (by advance, sorry if it is too elemental). Are you arbitrary taking $\epsilon=0$ for your proof? Isn't $\epsilon$ strictly bigger than one?

Comment: No, $\epsilon$ can be any positive number, but it cannot be $0$.  I am using the fact that the limit of an increasing sequence of numbers, each of which is bounded from above, exists and is not higher than the bound ($a_0$ in this case).

Comment: Thanks a lot @EricFisher. All your answers were very helpful for me.

Answer (score 4):

No you're assuming that $A$ includes it's supremum. You want to do something like the following:

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb R$ be a set such that $a_0 \in A$ is the largest value in $A$. Let $x \not\in A$, then we find that either $a_0 > x$ and thus $x$ is not an upper bound or $a_0 < x$ in which case $x$ is an upper bound but $a_0$ is an upper bound that is less then it, then for any number $x\not\in A$, $x\not=\sup A$, thus $\sup A \in A$ and then you're proof will show that the supremum must be $a_0$.

The issue with your proof was that you didn't show that the supremum was contained within $A$, you just kind of assumed it.

Answer (score 4):

To be frank this result is typical of many theorems in analysis which are *as trivial as they can be* and your approach is unnecessarily complicated and based on the unfounded assumption that *things in analysis are in general non-trivial*.

The result is an immediate consequence of the definitions of *maximum* and *supremum*. Let $a_{0}$ be the maximum of set $A$. Then by definition of maximum we have $a\leq a_{0}$ for all $a\in A$. Moreover if we take any number $b<a_{0}$ then it's just repeating the same thing that we have $a_{0}\in A$ and $a_{0}>b$. Thus $a_{0}$ is the supremum of $A$.

There is no need to show that $A$ is bounded above and invoke deep completeness property to justify the existence of $\sup A$. You can see that the above argument (and therefore the result in question) holds in any ordered field (eg $\mathbb{Q}$).

It is rather surprising that other answers here also make use of the completeness property unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

Let $b := sup A$, since $a_{0} \in A$ (is maximum), then $b \geq a_0$. Now we need to prove that $b \leq a_0$, for this suposse the contrary, this is $b > a_0$: As $a_0 \in A$ we have that $a_0 \geq a$ for all $a \in A$, then $a_0$ is upper bound of $A$, thus we have:

1. $b = sup A$
2. $b \geq a_0$
3. $a_0$ is upper bound

So contradiction! xd. Therefore $b \leq a_0$, finally $b = a_0$.